# Set initial active element, after resizing array of elements

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm kind a stuck on this. There is this standard tab menubar which receives it's data externally(array).
Initial state has full array, but during work, this array gets filtered. After filter, active class should mark first element whom receives data from newly filtered array.
But my logic, for some reason, marks element with index 1(letters: one) instead of zero(letters: zero) as active.
Filtering is good, no objection on that part.
Trouble is that this is done in React, so there are some guidelines that needs to be followed here.

Function that sets element active on click:

```
setActive(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    let elem = e.target;

    let len1 = elem.attributes.length;
    let obj1 = {};
    let name = null;
    let value = null;
    for(let i=0;i<len1;i++){

      let attr = elem.attributes[i];

      name = attr.name;
      value = attr.value;
      
      obj1[name] = value;
      
    }
    //Begin: Important for question asked.
    let allTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    let len2 = allTabs.length;
    for(let i=0;i<len2;i++){

      if(allTabs[i]===elem){

        this.setState({
          elemIndex: i
        });
        
      }
      
    }
    //End: Important for question asked.
    this.setState(obj1);

  }
```

Logic that filters out elements and resets active class, it's in render method:

```
let elemIndex = this.state.elemIndex;
    let active =  null;
    
    let menu = this.state.menu.filter((item, i) => {

      if(this.state.access_token===null && item==="register"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token===null && item==="login"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token!==null && item==="create"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token!==null && item==="show"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token!==null && item==="update"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token!==null && item==="delete"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(this.state.access_token!==null && item==="list"){
        
        return item;

      }
      
    });
    
    let lis = menu.map((item, i) => {
      console.log((elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0)), elemIndex, i);
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";
      
      return <li className="nav-item" key={i} id={i}>
        <a className={"nav-link" + active} data-toggle="tab" href={"menu"+(i+1)} onClick={this.setActive}>
          {item}
        </a>
      </li>;

    });

    let tabContents = menu.map((item, i) => {
      
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";

      return <div id={"menu"+(i+1)} key={i} className={"container tab-pane" + active}><br/>
        
        {item==="register" ? <Register register={this.register}/> : null}

        {item==="login" ? <Login login={this.login}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="create" ? <CreatePost createPost={this.createPost}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="show" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ShowPost onChange={this.onChange} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="list" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ListPosts posts={this.state.posts}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="update" && this.state.posts!==null ? <UpdatePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.updatePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="delete" && this.state.posts!==null ? <DeletePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.deletePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

      </div>;

    });
```

Other methods called are of no concern since they don't have anything to do with setting active class.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

First, i made filterisation an separate function and separate property to contain filtered array, second my logic for setuping active element was good, so no changes there. Third, i've made evaluation so that when filtered array is not empty, is used to map all tabbar elements.

Method for filtering:

```
filterize(){
    
    let menu = this.state.menu.filter((item, i) => {
      
      let access_token = this.state.access_token;
      if(access_token===null && item==="register"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token===null && item==="login"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token!==null && item==="create"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token!==null && item==="show"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token!==null && item==="update"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token!==null && item==="delete"){
        
        return item;

      }

      if(access_token!==null && item==="list"){
        
        return item;

      }
      
    });

    this.setState({
      filteredMenu: [...menu],
      elemIndex: 0
    });
    
  }

  componentDidMount(){//This needs to be since extracted logic isn't in render anymore.
    this.filterize();
  }
```

And in render method:

```
let elemIndex = this.state.elemIndex;
    let active =  null;
    
    let lis = this.state.filteredMenu ? this.state.filteredMenu.map((item, i) => {
      
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";
      
      return <li className="nav-item" key={i} id={i}>
        <a className={"nav-link" + active} data-toggle="tab" href={"menu"+(i+1)} onClick={this.setActive}>
          {item}
        </a>
      </li>;

    }) : this.state.menu.map((item, i) => {
      
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";
      
      return <li className="nav-item" key={i} id={i}>
        <a className={"nav-link" + active} data-toggle="tab" href={"menu"+(i+1)} onClick={this.setActive}>
          {item}
        </a>
      </li>;

    });

    let tabContents = this.state.filteredMenu ? this.state.filteredMenu.map((item, i) => {
      
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";

      return <div id={"menu"+(i+1)} key={i} className={"container tab-pane" + active}><br/>
        
        {item==="register" ? <Register register={this.register}/> : null}

        {item==="login" ? <Login login={this.login}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="create" ? <CreatePost createPost={this.createPost}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="show" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ShowPost onChange={this.onChange} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="list" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ListPosts posts={this.state.posts}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="update" && this.state.posts!==null ? <UpdatePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.updatePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="delete" && this.state.posts!==null ? <DeletePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.deletePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

      </div>;

    }) : this.state.menu.map((item, i) => {
      
      active = elemIndex===i || (i===0 && elemIndex===0) ? " active" : "";

      return <div id={"menu"+(i+1)} key={i} className={"container tab-pane" + active}><br/>
        
        {item==="register" ? <Register register={this.register}/> : null}

        {item==="login" ? <Login login={this.login}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="create" ? <CreatePost createPost={this.createPost}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="show" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ShowPost onChange={this.onChange} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="list" && this.state.posts!==null ? <ListPosts posts={this.state.posts}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="update" && this.state.posts!==null ? <UpdatePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.updatePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

        {this.state.access_token!==null && item==="delete" && this.state.posts!==null ? <DeletePost onChange={this.onChange} updatePost={this.deletePost} posts={this.state.posts} post={this.state.post}/> : null}

      </div>;

    });
```

Not sure if there is shorter code for this stuff, but at least it respect guidelines.